# Kernels and cokernels are universal

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

In the section on abelian categories in Lang’s *Algebra*, he says that,

> It is immediately verified that kernels and cokernels are universal in a suitable category, and hence uniquely determined up to a unique isomorphism if they exist.

What does he mean by a suitable category and how does one prove this?

Answer (score 2):

For an arrow $f:E\to F$ in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, consider the category of "arrows into $E$ whose composites with $f$ are the zero arrow". An arrow in this category between two objects $X\to E$ and $X'\to E$ is an arrow $X\to X'$ in $\mathcal{A}$ forming a commutative triangle over $E$. A kernel $k:E'\to E$ is just a terminal object in this category, and hence is unique up to unique isomorphism by a standard argument.